# MySQL errror: 150

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `countrytable` (
  `countryCode` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `currencyCode` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `currencySymbol` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `currencyIsRight` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `currencyName` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'US Dollar',
  `countryName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`countryCode`,`currencyCode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `countryCode_UNIQUE` (`countryCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am trying to create another table, which has a foreign key on `countrytable.currencyCode`. I keep getting the following error:

```
The specified relation was unable to be created.
MySQL said: Can't create table 'noteitdb.#sql-b8_13' (errno: 150)
```

The data types of the two columns exactly match. What could I be missing?

Comment: See in right side bar, other questions under 'Related' Heading.

Comment: countrytable.currencyCode is not unique

Comment: Yes it isn't unique, but I have a PK defined on the `countryCode`,`currencyCode` pair. Does defining a FK mean the referenced column is unique? Can't it be one from the set of valid values?

Comment: In your case PK is composite, and a pair (countryCode, currencyCode) is unique. The FK should refer to unique field(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `countrytable`   
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`currencyCode`, `countryCode`);
```

currencyCode should be indexed first. Refer MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: Worked! Thanks a bunch. I still have to understand why the orders matter.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You need a UNIQUE key on `currencyCode` alone, not a compound one.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a Foreign Key constraint that references `CurrencyCode`, then you need a `UNIQUE` (or a Primary Key) constraint on this column in this table:

```
ALTER TABLE countrytable   
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (currencyCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `unsigned` from PK column.

Comment: While this is not the solution here. I had an issue where I needed to match the signed/unsigned of two INT fields before I could create my Foreign Key.

Comment: Helpful answer. I also had a mismatch between signed/unsigned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
execute below line before creating/altering table table :

 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
 // all your sql craete ,alter  etc goes here  and then below 
 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS option specifies whether or not to check foreign key constraints for InnoDB tables. 
-- Specify to check foreign key constraints (this is the default)
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
 
-- Do not check foreign key constraints
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
When to Use : Temporarily disabling referential constraints (set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS to 0) is useful when you need to re-create the tables and load data in any parent-child order
```